# Connecting to the MySQL DataBase with Solr

Tags: mysql, database, solr, dih

I'm new in StackOverflow; I hope you can help me.

I have a problem with `Solr 6.0.0`, I try to explain:
I'm trying to connect my `MySQL DB` to `Solr` to index it.

To set the `DataImportHandler` I modified `manage-schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` files and I created the `db-data-config.xml` file with the access data to my DB.

I enter in the Solr user panel, click on the Collection created and later on dataImport. Now I click on "Execute" to make indexing and I get the message:

```
"Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
Requests: 1, Fetched: 3, Skipped: 0, Processed: 0".
```

After I click on the item "Query" in my Collection and later on "Execute Query" 
but the ResponseHeader does not find anything:

```
response:{numFound:0, start:0, docs:[]}
```

I cannot tell, if it is a problem with query or connection to DB.

This is the "db-data-config.xml" file:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboard" 
              user="dashBoard" 
              password="41From!!Z3r0"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="utente" query="select ID, Nome, Cognome from utenti">
       <field column="ID" name="solr_id"/>
       <field column="Nome" name="solr_nome"/>
       <field column="Cognome" name="solr_cognome"/>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You can find what the problem using the "Logging" menu in the left pane Just below the SOLR icon (2nd menu) and update the log info to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: This is the Warning message that is shown in "Logging":
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id ........
how to solve ?

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks SASIKUMAR S.

But now how can I create a front-end for searching with Solr?

Comment: Sounds Good :)
You can use JQuery or Angular or any other front-end framework that you are familiar with.
Solr is basically a restful web-service so the SOLR URL will respond for you in different formats such as JSON,XML,etc.., 
One can retrieve the results using the URL and render the results into the screen as required.

Comment: Kindly post the answer. @[mrsmile19](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6430688/mrsmile19)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you